# What is the maximum amount of time considered appropriate to respond to a recruiter?

Tags: recruitment, email

I receive a reasonable number of unsolicited emails from recruiters (ie. Skype, Microsoft, Amazon). Often I'm not interested in the opportunity, but I may be interested in working for the company in the future. Do I have to reply to the recruiters immediatly or can I just ignore them until the time if/when I decide I want to work for the company?

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9457/how-long-can-i-wait-to-respond-to-recruiter-e-mail Duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep your options open, an immediate reply is the best choice. If you have a copy and paste handy, it takes all of 2 minutes and you have a high likelihood of staying in the recruiters data base with  adjectives like "decisive", "easy to work with", "good communicator", "future prospect".

Something along the lines of:

> "Thanks for your message, I  appreciate you reaching out to me since I
>   think XXX is really interesting company. Unfortunately I'm currently
>   fully engaged and not on looking for a new opportunity but if it's
>   okay with you, I'll keep your name on file so we can connect if a
>   future opportunity emerges"

If there is something specific you are looking for, you can certainly put this in there as well.

> "I'm certainly interested in working at XXX but this opportunity
>   doesn't feel like a good fit I'm looking more for a senior level
>   technical role in web development ..."